# How to bold (\textbf) an entire example in gb4e?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I am presenting linguistic examples using `gb4e`. For one example, I would like to make the entire example bold, either the source utterance or the entire thing (including gloss and free translation). When I compile the code below, the bolded example begins on on the line below the example number. I have many examples like this, and I need to bold one of four options in each one. How can I eliminate the extra line without applying `\textbf` to each individual word?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex \textbf{
        \gll sak=en du xu tat nanen chushma rughd.\\
             we=\textsc{cl} with our father mother hot-spring went\\
        \glt `We went to the hot-springs with our parents.'
                    }
    \ex 
        \gll sak=en du xu tat nanen chushma rughd.\\
             we=\textsc{cl} with our father mother hot-spring went\\
        \glt `We went to the hot-springs with our parents.'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i've not tried this, but perhaps `\bfseries` (since it doesn't take an argument) would have a more "enduring" result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `\textbf{...}` by `{\bfseries ...}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex {\bfseries
        \gll sak=en du xu tat nanen chushma rughd.\\
             we=\textsc{cl} with our father mother hot-spring went\\
        \glt `We went to the hot-springs with our parents.'
           }         
    \ex 
        \gll sak=en du xu tat nanen chushma rughd.\\
             we=\textsc{cl} with our father mother hot-spring went\\
        \glt `We went to the hot-springs with our parents.'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to combine `\textbf` with `\textsc`(*necessarily*) you should add something like `\usepackage{bold-extra}` in the *preamble*. (the result is not very good but it works).